# Exchange 2010 SP3 Apply KB4536989 Error Ended Prematurely

Tags: exchange

I am not sure if this is the right place to ask this question.
I was trying to apply the latest KB4536989 patch to my Exchange 2010 SP3 server which has hub transport, mail server and edge transport in one place.
When I tried to apply it, it came back with the following error.
I reran it again by using "Run as Admin" but the same result.
Does anyone encounter the same error?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try running from elevated command prompt:

msiexec /update Exchange2010-KB4536989-x64-en.msp

I encountered the same issue and so far, running from command prompt is allowing it to proceed as expected.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I found a similar thread "**[Exchange 2010 SP3 Apply KB4536989 Error Ended Prematurely](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/913ea38b-3e39-4289-bb72-c345d0bd8e20/exchange-2010-sp3-apply-kb4536989-error-ended-prematurely?forum=exchange2010)**", you could refer to **Vera Shen** or others' replies. Hope it helpful to you :)